# Do animation after view get displayed in view pager (android)

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, android-animation

Hi I am new to android and I am doing one simple application. My application contain one simple activity in witch it contains view pager. my view pager having no of screens 3. SO my view pager working fine. my first and second screen contains one button when i click on that button it will goes to third screen `setCurrentItem(2);`.

now what i want is when i go third screen it will render one view and few sec only like after completely rendering that view do some animation like flip animation.

what happen in reality when i click on buttons it directly go to that screen but not rendering that default view. it directly starts animation...

My code looks like

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity {

    private final int NUM_SCREENS = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        }

    private OnClickListener signin = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                vp.setCurrentItem(2);
                // ******* do some animation on view 3 in pager views ....          
        }

    };

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_SCREENS;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            View view = null;
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/sf_cartoonist_hand_bold.ttf");
            if (position == 0) {
                // display view1
                // on button click call sign in

            } else if (position == 1) {
                //display view 2
                //on button click call sign in
            } else if (position == 2) {

                //display view 3

            }

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }
    }


}
```

what i need after clicking on button it skips to view3 display for few sec and after that do animation... how to do that?
need help.....
thank you .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Runnable` you can hold your animation until your view is not load it properly, you have to measure that in how much seconds your view get load, so you can pass delay as per your view get load time, something like below:

```
Runnable runnableimage = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            //HERE YOUR ANIMATION
                image.startAnimation(animFast);

            }
        };
```

It start your animation after `2000 MilliSec`

> handler.postDelayed(runnableimage, 2000);

Comment: hye robin thank you for reply ... it's working for me.actually i tried flip kind of thing and its working now thank you for help...

Answer (score 1):

Use `animate()` with start delay:

`mView.animate().rotationBy(360).setDuration(3000).setStartDelay(2000).start();`

Comment: Hye Singularity (:P) thank you for reply .. your solution also works but i want flip kind of animation that's why i am using custome animation.. but u r solution also working fine ... Thank you for help...

Comment: @nilkash For that use `rotationXBy()` or `rotationYBy` or combo , to flip around axis.